# buffered withLatestFrom

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I need something similar to [withLatestFrom](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom) which corresponds to a diagram below:

```
---------A-----------------B--
-1-2-3------4------5-6-7-8----

--------[A,[123]]---------------[B,[45678]]
```

Is there any way to implement such behavior with RxJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologise that I'm not a javascript coder, but this works in .NET. Hopefully you can translate.

```
var xs = new Subject<string>();
var ys = new Subject<string>();

var qs =
    xs.Publish(pxs =>
        ys.Buffer(() => pxs)
            .Zip(pxs, (numbers, letter) => new { letter, numbers }));
```

The `.Publish(pxs =>` operator takes a single observable, subscribes to it only once and shares that subscription within the lambda. It prevents multiple subscriptions of the source and synchronizes the production of the values from `pxs` within the lambda.

The `ys.Buffer(() => pxs` takes all values of `ys` and turns the values into a series of lists broken up at the point when `pxs` produces values.

Finally the `.Zip(...)` takes the values from `pxs` and pairs them up with the lists produced by `.Buffer(...)`.

```
qs.Subscribe(q => Console.WriteLine(q));

ys.OnNext("1");
ys.OnNext("2");
ys.OnNext("3");
xs.OnNext("A");
ys.OnNext("4");
ys.OnNext("5");
ys.OnNext("6");
ys.OnNext("7");
ys.OnNext("8");
xs.OnNext("B");

ys.OnCompleted();
xs.OnCompleted();
```

It produces:

[image: result]

---

Here's the translated javascript version:

```
var qs = xs.publish(
    pxs =>
      ys.buffer(() => pxs).zip(pxs, (numbers, letter) => [ letter, numbers ])
);
```

Comment: I guess the code is compatible(except generics <T>) with JS:) The only problem, my diagram confused you and I need a little bit different behavior. Please, check the updated diagram or the other answer

Comment: Upvoted yestreday:) I will accept it in the evening if @user3743222 doesn't mind. Technically he proposed valid solution earlier

Comment: Can you please explain what the publish operator do in this case?

Comment: @Enigmativity An explanation of how this all works would be enormously helpful. Your high reputation lends the expectation of high quality answers. :) Upvoting in good faith.

Comment: @kharandziuk - I've added an explanation.

Comment: @m59 - I've added an explanation.

Comment: Hi, @Enigmativity I just realized that the best possible explanation is if you just explain what happens in case when we remove `Publish`. Can I ask you to add it?

Comment: @kharandziuk - In this case the `.Publish` does nothing as `new Subject<string>()` is effectively a hot observable, but `xs` were a cold observable it would prevent multiple subscriptions to the original source. So, as a general rule, when I use an observable twice within the one query I pop a `.Publish` to make sure it's only one subscription.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/n1nsjqnx/1/) seems to be working. It is based on the `sample` operator but there are other ways to do the same.

```
var ta_message = document.getElementById('ta_message');
var ta_result = document.getElementById('ta_result');

function emits ( who, who_ ) {return function ( x ) {
 who.innerHTML = [who.innerHTML, who_ + " emits " + JSON.stringify(x)].join("\n");
};}

function pushValue (arr, el){arr.push(el); return arr;}

var sourceCounter = 0;
var samplerCounter = 0;
var source$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.getElementById('source'), 'click')
  .map(function(){return sourceCounter++;})
  .do(emits(ta_source, 'source'))
  .share();
var sampler$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.getElementById('sampler'), 'click')
  .map(function(){return String.fromCharCode(65+samplerCounter++);})
  .do(emits(ta_sampler, 'sampler'))
  .share();

var bufferedSource$ = sampler$
  .startWith('0')
  .flatMapLatest(function (x){
    console.log("x",x)
    return source$.scan(pushValue,[])
  })  
  .do(emits(ta_sampler, 'bufferedSource$'));

var sampledSource$ = bufferedSource$
  .sample(sampler$)
  .do(emits(ta_result, 'sampledSource'))
  .withLatestFrom(sampler$, 
        function (bufferedValues, samplerValue){
          return "" +samplerValue + bufferedValues;
        })
  .do(emits(ta_result, 'result'))

//sampler$.connect();
sampledSource$.subscribe(function(){});
```

Comment: I'm new to RP... but shouldn't variables to store state not be needed?

Comment: which variables are you referring to? If these are the counters, you could do a `scan` and have the same but it does not really matter because this is just to create a dummy source for the example. The real solution is down that part. `source` and `sampler` are supposed to be given.

Comment: `sourcecounter` and `samplerCounter`

Comment: Hey @user3743222. What do you think about the other answer? it looks much shorter

Comment: If you remove all the logging, write it in ES6, my answer is not so long. That said, the one you mention works totally fine and is definitely shorter (maybe faster?). Accept whichever you like the most. Actually I am now going to try to understand the magic in this other answer (it uses `publish` with a selector, which is pretty poorly documented so it is a great non-trivial example from which to learn). And last thing, there is a third possibility to do the same with `merge` and `scan` but that's also longer (5 lines).

Comment: @kharandziuk I'm still cautious of this answer because of those state variables. The whole idea of Reactive programming is to eliminate state variable and declare state behavior (how does something react) instead.

Comment: as I already said, for the context of this example, it does not matter. For khrandziuk real usage, `source$` and `sampler$` will be given, from there on there is no 'state' variables. This is like saying 'here you have a `console.log`, it is a side effect`. So what? This is to prove the example is working correctly. In your code, you remove it.